# Combine multiple typescript files into one typescript definition file

Tags: typescript

I need this for distributing libraries in TypeScript in a single file. Is there a way to merge multiple typescript files into (one js file + one typescript definition) file?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by removes all the static information?  Typescript will contact to a single file, are you using references like this?:  ```///<reference path='dgrid.d.ts' />```

Comment: @7zark7 made the question more explicit. Should be clear now.

Comment: Should TypeScript libraries be distributed as TypeScript or as JavaScript with an associated definition file?

Comment: @MiMo I think steve's answer is where you were going.  --declaration for multiple files generates a .d.ts for each file. I tested it this morning: github.com/basarat/ts-test/tree/master/tests/compileToSingle I would be okay if it was (one js + one d.ts)

Comment: @BASarat There's a flaw in your test.  You specify --out or --declaration but you need to specify both to get a single .js and single .d.ts.

Comment: Flaw fixed and works. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create a library you could compile it as follows:

```
tsc --outfile mylib.js --declaration app.ts
```

This means you get the compiled JavaScript and a TypeScript definition file, and it is still just as simple to use in TypeScript as if it was a single TypeScript file.

You don't need to specify all the files you want to combine, the compiler will walk all the dependencies and bring them all into one file in the correct order. In the example above I have specified only `app.ts`, but all of the references will be walked and they will all make it into the combined `mylib.js` and the associated `mylib.d.ts` files.

Comment: I am afraid the author wants to combine multiple TypeScript files in a single TypeScript file, and not use a JavaScript file as a .ts file.

Example: if he has File1.ts, File2.ts, ..., FileN.ts, he wants to run a command that generates TheUltimateSingleFileTypeScriptLibrary.ts so he can deploy his TypeScript library for other developers to use in their projects.

Maybe I'm wrong, but that was my understanding of his question.

Comment: @JefersonOliveira is correct. Additionally --declaration for multiple files generates a .d.ts for each file. I tested it this morning: https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/tree/master/tests/compileToSingle I would be okay if it was (one js + one d.ts)

Comment: I'm going to repeat myself in case someone reads this thread but not the other.  If --out *and* --declaration are specified you do get a single .d.ts file.

Comment: @JefferyGrajkowski it works mate. Thanks. Would prefer a single .ts instead of (.js + .d.ts) but I should post a separate question for that.

Comment: @BASarat I have corrected a point in your edit - you don't need to specify all of your files as the compiler will walk the chain of references for you.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using the "--module AMD" directive, or maybe this changed from a previous version, but this does not work for me.  I get a single compiled app.js file, and multiple .d.ts files are generated in their respective locations.  The .d.ts file for app.ts is not a merged definition.  (tsc version 1.0.1.0)

Comment: @JefferyGrajkowski it is still works well for typescript 1.6.3. thanks!

Comment: Results in a lot of duplicate declarations for me.  Also not suitable for putting them all under a single module declaration.

Comment: Is there a way to define this behaviour in tsconfig.json, instead of launching it from terminal?

Comment: @jayarjo yes - all the flags you specify on the command line are also available in the compiler options section of your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Option 'out' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5.  Use 'outFile' instead.