# merge two different package typescript definition files into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

i have two typescript definition packages `@types/package-a` `@types/package-b` and want to merge two definitions into one definition. is there a way?

```
package-a.d.ts [export package-a {...}]
package-b.d.ts [exports package-b {...}]

package-mine.d.ts 
[ export newtype { ...package-a-objecttype, ...package-b-objecttype } ]
```

i have looked at the below and this is not what i am looking for.
[Combine multiple typescript files into one typescript definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660277/combine-multiple-typescript-files-into-one-typescript-definition-file)

Comment: Do you have some minimal but real codes for packages A and B? And what do you want for the interface of the merged new type? Are you actually asking how to merge two object types, and the fact that they are from two packages is not important?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: file.d.ts one: `export <TypeObjectPackageA>` and file2.d.ts both: `export <TypeObjectPackageB>` which is imported into third filethree `export [TypeObjectPackageC]<...TypeObjectPackageA, ...TypeObjectPackageB>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `export * from 'package'` re-export statement.

```js
export * from 'package-a';
export * from 'package-b';
```

Comment: does this apply for typings as well? second `package-a` is a object type and `package-b` is an object type. can i merge both in any way?